# Moving between two Activities including data send and received, without loosing data

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

I am trying to develop an app with two activities. After open, the app in the main activity user will input some number and do some general math calculation (such as Add, multiply, etc) by clicking the button. Then for another specific calculation user will move to 2nd activities (FabricCost) by clicking a button. In 2nd activity, the user will do some calculation and get a result. Then the user will send that result to the main activity by clicking a button. But the problem is, after sending that result, when the user going back to the main activity all the previous calculations of the main activity are already lost. Also when the user again going back to the 2nd activity by clicking the button, there also no result remaining, everything lost. I want to keep all the user input and data as it is in all the activities. I have tried with "onSaveInstanceState" but did not work. Please help me.

code by which going to 2nd activity from main activity

```
btnfabrateperkg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent btnfabrateperkg = new Intent (MainActivity.this, FabricCost.class);
                startActivity(btnfabrateperkg);
```

code by which sending data to main activity from 2nd activity

```
btnsentresult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                String stetfabriccostperkg = etfabriccostperkg.getText().toString();

                Intent btnsentresult = new Intent (FabricCost.this, MainActivity.class);

                btnsentresult.putExtra( "etfabriccostperkg",stetfabriccostperkg);

                startActivity(btnsentresult);
```

code by which main activity getting result from 2nd activity

```
etfabrate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra( "etfabriccostperkg"));
```

I have tried with "onSaveInstanceState" in main activity but didn't work, code as below

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        savedInstanceState.putDouble(etbl.getText().toString(), 1.11);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) return;

            double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble(etbl.getText().toString());

        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to reach the result. You have to pass value every time from activity to another activity.

Step1 Going to 2nd activity from main activity

```
String stetfabriccostperkg = etfabriccostperkg.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent (FabricCost.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("myobjects", stetfabriccostperkg);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RESULT);
```

Step2 Save data in main activity while come from 2nd activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESULT) {
                        // make use of "data" = profit
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                            if (b != null) {
                            String str = b.getString("myobject");
                         }
                        } else if (resultCode == 0) {
                            //Write your code if there's no result
                            System.out.println("RESULT CANCELLED");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Step3 2nd activity on onCreate add below line

```
 Intent intent = this.getIntent();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
 String str =  bundle.getString("myobjects");
```

Step4 Going to main activity from 2nd activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myobject", str); //str is result to pass Main Activity
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Hello Sir, Kindly note that, in my following apps, with the existing code, I can easily move from one activity to another activity and also able to send data/result from 2nd activity to main activity. But problem is that, when I click button to send result to main activity, its open main activity and show only the result which I have sent from 2nd activity, but all the other previous user input are not remaining there. But if go back to main activity by pressing back button all the previous input remaining same. Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: @EHBipul As i understood. you want to save/persist data in activity. Code to save and restore instance state, take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

If the data you need to persist is really large, you can use a retained fragment instead, as explained here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: Dear Satish, As I mentioned bottom of my post that, I have tried with "onSaveInstanceState" in main activity but didn't work, please see the code in already posted in my question. Moreover if possible then please give me link of some example of code because I am very new developer. thank you in advance for your kind support.